# Yii assigning foreign key value using user Identity object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, yii-components

In my web application I have 3 tables user types named `producer_offer,consumer_req,admin`, and a `user table, producer,consumer` . 
The relationship

```
user.id=producer_offer.offered_by
user.id=consumer_req.requested_by
```

Basically based on the user logged in with user id it should automatically assign  based on the user type and id to the foreign keys in consumer_req and producer_offer table
I tried the following code but its not working in the userController

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new User;
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
        if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
            if ($model->save()) {

                if($model->user_type=='producer'){
                    $producer=new ProducerOffer;
                    $producer->offered_by=$model->id;
                    //$producer->save();
                }
                if($model->user_type=='consumer'){

                    $consumer=new ConsumerReq;
                    $consumer->requested_by=$model->id;
                    //$consumer->save();
                }

                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
            }
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
                'model'=>$model,
        ));
        }
```

**My code for the userIdentity class**

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity

{

private $_id;


public function authenticate()
{
    $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array(
            'email'=>$this->username));
    if ($user === null) {

        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    } else if ($user->pass !==
    hash_hmac('sha256', $this->password,
            Yii::app()->params['encryptionKey']) ) {

        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    } else {
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        $this->setState('type', $user->user_type);
        $this->setState('id', $user->id);
        $this->_id = $user->id;

    }
    return !$this->errorCode;

}

public function getId() {
    return $this->_id;

}

}
```

In my siteController I have this code in the `actionSetup()` for assigning user types

```
public function actionSetup(){
        $auth->assign($user->type,$user->id);
    }
```

But I am getting the following error when I execute,this

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`AFFM`.`producer_offer`, CONSTRAINT `producer_offer_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`offered_by`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `producer_offer` (`offered_vegetable`, `offered_qty`, `unit_cost`, `unit_delivery_cost`, `offered_date`, `booking_status`, `booked_by`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6)
```

Comment: hi, can you post the model for producer_offer table?

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting a record in the `product_offer` table, but you're not insereting the foreign key field `offered_by`. If you want to allow to this to be empty, you have to set this field at NULL in you database.

Comment: ok if i set it to NULL should I use migrations to reflect the changes in the web application or I can directly change it in my models?

Comment: That depends on you situation and preferences. If your application is in multiple setups, i would recommend to create a migration. If you have only a development setup then that's not necercary.

Comment: ok.. can you please tell me if I can use session variables ? and assign them to foreign keys?

Comment: Sessions and database are 2 complete apart things, so no, you can't use session variable.

Comment: no the table is designed in such a way that  the user.id primary key is the foreign key id of  producer_offered.offered_by and user.id is the foreign key of consumerReq.requested_by